# OpenLayers-2.12 map width variable with Bootstrap

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, openlayers

I'm using an OpenLayers-2.12 map inside an HTML5 page styled with the CSS framework Bootstrap.
Is that possible to have a variable map width, as demonstrated [here](http://ol3js.org/ol3/master/examples/zoomslider.html) with OpenLayers version 2.12?
If so, could you please give me an example?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A width of 100% (CSS) `width: 100%;` on the div where OpenLayers is applied works with OpenLayers 2.12